# How to add Escape characters' " ' with gcloud sql import csv command?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, data-import

I want to upload data into Google cloudsql instance from csv file stored on GCS bucket. I am using **postgresql database** and to import csv files using **gcloud sql import csv** command in my shell script. There is an issue as some csv files contains **"** characters and to ignore that I want to add **"** as Escape character but **gcloud sql import csv** command doesn't have any fields to add escape character. Does anybody have anyidea on that?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, to import CSV files to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL, the CSV file has to follow a [specific format](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#:%7E:text=csv%20files%20must%20have%20one%20line%20for%20each%20row%20of%20data%20and%20use%20comma-separated%20fields.).

We can also see that for [the command you're using](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/csv) there isn't any parameter that fits your requirements.

Instead, as an alternative, I'd use some sort of [lint](https://csvlint.io/) or text editor and try to massively remove the characters that conflict you, if possible.